Proposed transactions from Safe apikit are failing without any explanation
I was having a G013 error when I did this.
const transactions = [{
to: to_address,
value: amount,
data: getData(amount,token_address,url,to_address),
}]
So then I added this fields:
const transactions = [{
to: to_address,
value: amount,
data: getData(amount,token_address,url,to_address),
safeTxGas: "0",
baseGas: "0",
gasPrice:'0',
gasToken:'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
refundReceiver: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
nonce: 8,
}]
And the transaction failed on when executing.

Thank you! Could you please provide more details on the transaction parameters (to, value, amount, token_address, etc.) as well as how this data is used in the code? It will help us debugging the issue. Thank you in advance  Best, Louis

I believe the G013 error refers to having insufficient funds to cover for the gas fee of the transaction.
See this answer:
GS013 error when executing Gnosis Safe transaction
Feel free to mark the question as solved if it answered the problem. If not, please let me know!
All the best!
